# JComboBox not showing results

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jcombobox

i am trying to set the values in a JCombobox based on a for and if loop, on an arraylist.

```
     //salesman=the name of the combobox
    salesman = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
 salesman.setModel(model);

/*company is an object of Company class, that gets set with a setter method to ensure 
that the gui will be pointing to the right object. and it does contains the data i want, so 
i am sure that company is not the problem */       
//loop tp set box list 
for (Employee current : company.getArray()){

 if (current instanceof Salesman) {
   salesman.addItem(current.getCode());
  }

}
```

but the combobox stays empty. why is that ?

Comment: Actually, it may be not empty (but rather small, if *Salesman.getCode().toString()* returns null :))

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, I'd suggest you the following:

1. Override the ***toString()*** method of ***Salesman*** class to have desirable visual representation (i.e. *code*).
2. Add Salesmen, not codes to combo box ***model***.

Answer (score 1):

Add the items to the model not directly to the ComboBox.   Also, use barti_ddu's recommendations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the combobox to its parent container?

The above code should work fine as long as there are some instances of Salesman present.

You say you're sure the company is not the object but have you checked what you're actually adding to the ComboBoxModel? Also, you don't need instantiate your own DefaultcomboBoxModel as you get one "for free" with the JComboBox

Comment: i wrote a test method where i print the values of "current".
when i call that method in the other JFrame tha calls this one ( by using AddOrder.test(); it prints me the two codes ( 45,46)

Answer (score 0):

If you just add some test Strings to the JComboBox, are they displayed?

If they are it might be something wrong with the .getCode() method.

Also, try removing the DefaultComboBoxModel, because this isn't required.

Comment: if a manually add salesman.addItem("blablabla");, it gets dispalyed. The getCode(), does nothing but return the Salesman code number.

Answer (score 0):

OK PROBLEM SOLVED! i just added to the constructor of the class a Company class object, that gets set with setCompany.

Comment: It's good that you managed to solve your problem.  Now you need to mark one of these answers as your accepted answer - either mark your own, or the one you found most useful.